# make looping insert database from codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, loops

i have a form that insert loop data. the problem is even i don't insert new data on my form,  my database still adding a new one.i can add more one data in same data, but when create new data after first one,get me twice data with empty value.
here is my code

**Controller**

```
$doc_number  = $_POST['doc_number'];
    $closedby    = $_POST['closedby'];
    $reasonclose = $_POST['reasonclose'];
    $description = $_POST['description'];


for($i=0;$i<count($closedby);$i++) {

        $solved = array(            
            'DOC_NUMBER'    => $doc_number,
            'LOB'           => $closedby,
            'REASON'        => $reasonclose,
            'DESCRIPTION'   => $description,
            'CREATE_DATE'   => $dateop,
            'ID_SOLVED'     => ++$num
        );
        $this->db->insert('NEWS_EVENT_SOLVED_TAB',$solved);
        var_dump($solved);
    }
```

**VIEW**

```
<div class="controls" style="margin-left: 70px;">
<input id="idf" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $num;?>" />
<input id="idf" type="hidden" value="1" />          
<div id="divSolved"></div>
<button type="button" onclick="addLob(); return false;">Add LOB</button>
</div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
function addLob() {
    var idf = $("#idf").val();
    var stre = "<p id='srow" + idf +"'>"+
            "<select id='closedby_"+idf+"' name='closedby[]' class='form-control span3'>"+
                "<option value=''>Choose One LOB</option>"+
                "<option value='alkes'>Alkes</option>"+
                "<option value='bd'>BD</option>"+
                "<option value='cosmetic'>Cosmetic</option>"+
                "<option value='feed'>Feed</option>"+
                "<option value='food'>Food</option>"+
                "<option value='import'>Import</option>"+
                "<option value='logistic'>Logistic</option>"+
                "<option value='pharma'>Pharma</option>"+
                "<option value='purchasing'>Purchasing</option>"+
                "<option value='qa'>QA</option>"+
            "</select>"+
            "<select id='reasonclose_"+idf+"' name='reasonclose' class='form-control span3'>"+
                "<option value=''>Choose One Reason</option>"+
                "<option value='Claim Insurance'>Claim Insurance</option>"+
                "<option value='Claim Principal'>Claim Principal</option>"+
                "<option value='Claim Transporter'>Claim Transporter</option>"+
                "<option value='Sample'>Sample</option>"+
                "<option value='Sold To Customer'>Sold To Customer</option>"+
            "</select>"+
            "<textarea rows='2' id='description_"+idf+"' name='description' placeholder='Keterangan'/>"+
            "<a href='#' style='color:#3399FD;' onclick='hapusElemen(\"#srow" + idf + "\"); return false;'><img alt='' src='<?php echo themeUrl(); ?>images/delete.png'></a>"+
        "</p>";

    $("#divSolved").append(stre);
    idf++;
    $("#idf").val(idf);
  }
  function hapusElemen(idf) {
    $(idf).remove();
  }

function confirm(){
var isi = '<div align="" class="text-">Please wait while processing...<br /><img alt="" src="<?php echo themeUrl(); ?>img/ajax_loader.gif" align=""></div>';
$('.modal-body').html(isi);
var modalWidth = 300;
var left = (screen.availWidth - (modalWidth * 2));
$('button.close').hide();
$('#myModal').css({'width':modalWidth+'px','left':left+'px'}).modal({backdrop:'static',keyboard:false,show:true});

var hotdata = $('#productclose').handsontable('getInstance');
hstable = JSON.stringify({'data':hotdata.getData()});

//alert(lob);
for(var i=1; i<$('#idf').val(); i++) {
    $.post('<?php echo base_url('report/news_event/confirmed'); ?>',{
        doc_number      : $('#id_number').val(),
        closedby        : $('#closedby_'+i).val(),
        reasonclose     : $('#reasonclose_'+i).val(),
        description     : $('#description_'+i).val(),
        itemdata        : hstable
        //datenumber    : $('#reminder_date').val()
    },function() {
                    //alert($('#closedby').val());
                    //location.reload();
            });
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The issue you've got is that when you submit, even if there's nothing added, is that there will still be one `$_POST['closedby']` record, but the value might be blank.

In the for loop, you should check to see if `$_POST['closedby']` is empty/blank or generally the default for the options.  If it is, then don't do the insert.  Something like:

```
if (!empty($_POST['closedby'][$i])
{
    // insert code
}
```

As a side note, you should use models to interact with your database, and have the controller call functions in the model.

Comment: i'll try,but still adding data on my database.